# Write to file via jenkins post-groovy script on slave

Tags: groovy, hudson, jenkins

I'd like to do something very simple: Create/write to a file located in the remote workspace of a slave via the jenkins [groovy post-build script plug-in](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin)

```
def props_file = new File(manager.build.workspace.getRemote() + "/temp/module.properties")

def build_num = manager.build.buildVariables.get("MODULE_BUILD_NUMBER").toInteger()

def build_props = new Properties()
build_props["build.number"] = build_num

props_file.withOutputStream { p ->
    build_props.store(p, null)
}
```

The last line fails, as the file doesn't exist. I'm thinking it has something to do with the output stream pointing to the master executor, rather than the remote workspace, but I'm not sure:

```
Groovy script failed:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /views/build_view/temp/module.properties (No such file or directory)
```

Am I not writing to the file correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for words `The post build plugin runs on the manager and doing it as you say will fail if you are working with slaves!` on the plugin page (the link to which you've provided) and see if the workaround there helps.

Comment: There must be a more elegant way than def a env var specifically for a situation like this one.

Thinking this might be what I need: http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/FilePath.html

Comment: The workaround was an afterthought. The crux is that it runs on the master, you go from there.

Answer (score 12):

While writing onto slave you need to check the channel first and then you can successfully create a file handle and start reading or writing to that file:

```
if(manager.build.workspace.isRemote())
{
    channel = manager.build.workspace.channel;
}

fp = new hudson.FilePath(channel, manager.build.workspace.toString() + "\\test.properties")

if(fp != null)
{
    String str = "test";
    fp.write(str, null); //writing to file
    versionString = fp.readToString(); //reading from file
}
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Instead of \\test.properties you need to add /test.properties since it gives an IOException

Comment: If the job is not remote there will be no channel

Answer (score 0):

Does the folder `/views/build_view/temp` exist?

If not, you will need to do `new File( "${manager.build.workspace.remote}/temp" ).mkdirs()`

Comment: It does exist. I'm just not sure where the outputStream is being written to (master or slave?)